Plots the world map with undesired horizontal lines and Latitude/longitude grid and labeling with ggplot
Everything is set to default and appears to be fine.
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)
library(rnaturalearth)

# Data:
coast <- ne_coastline(scale = 50, returnclass = "sf") 

ggplot(coast)+
  geom_sf()+
  coord_sf(expand = FALSE,
           label_graticule = "SWNE")


But the problem arises when trying to adjust the center of the map to the Pacific region:
coast1 = coast |> st_shift_longitude()
ggplot(coast1)+
  geom_sf()+
  coord_sf(expand = FALSE,
           label_graticule = "SWNE")


This may be a long time ago: End of https://ggplot2-book.org/coord.html https://ggplot2-book.org/coord_files/figure-html/map-world-1.png  Any new ways to fix it lately?
Edit1: Thanks for the advice provided in the comments. st_break_antimeridian This does work, but there are still some issues with the latitude/longitude grid labeling.
plate_carree_crs <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +lon_wrap=160"
coast2 = coast |> 
  st_break_antimeridian(lon_0 = 160) |>
  st_transform(plate_carree_crs)

ggplot(coast2)+
  geom_sf()+
  coord_sf(expand = FALSE)



In the linked duplicate, the answer was to use sf::st_break_antimeridian. If you can't get this working, please [edit] your question to explain why your case is different.
